# Can I use a 70 amp panel for a 30 amp service feed?

Tags: electrical, wiring, installation, subpanel

I am running a subpanel off of a 30 amp breaker, I need to run a smaller subpanel off of that. Can I use a 70 amp rated panel for my 30 amp service feed, so that I will have room in the panel to put in a 20 amp double pole breaker?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that within the subpanel I will also have a 15 amp breaker next to the 20 amp double pole braker. I just need to know if it's possible and safe despite what code says, all do respect to codes.

Comment: The biggest thing is to make sure you get a panel with enough spaces.  More spaces are cheap, and the last thing you want to do is run out of spaces later, just because you didn't think about expansion room.  Don't be afraid to go "a little crazy".

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. It is quite typical to have a sub-panel (non-service panel) rated higher than the feeder that feeds it. The rating of the panel is just the maximum it can be fed with.

Comment: Thank you, I also finally found this video,    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Z0xyT4lPzw